# querysave event validation

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a form. The form fields are validated in the querysave event. The validation goes like this. I have some fields to be validated for its presence during save. i.e., when i click a check box and dont enter the details in its field, it should show a error message box while saving. The validation works fine for a new document. My question is

1. how to make it work for both new document and edit mode?
2. The error message is not getting displayed the second time when i click on save.i.e., when i click ok in the messagebox, dont enter data and click save, its getting saved. how to make it check for validation everytime when clicked on save.

Kindly help me. Please dont mind if my questions are obvious and simple because i m a fresher. Thanks in advance.

The script goes below,
The first part calculating ref num for new docs and secong part validating fields,

```
Sub Querysave(Source As Notesuidocument, Continue As Variant)

Dim w               As        New notesuiworkspace
Dim uidoc           As        notesuidocument
Set uidoc           =         w.CurrentDocument

Dim SESS            As        New NotesSession
Dim Doc             As        NotesDocument
Dim RefView         As        NotesView
Dim DB              As        NotesDatabase
Dim RefDoc          As        NotesDocument
Set DB              =         SESS.CurrentDatabase
Set Doc             =         uidoc.Document
Set RefView         =         DB.GetView("System\AutoNo")

If uidoc.IsNewDoc = True Then 
    Financial_year        =  Clng(Right$(Cstr(Year(Now)),3)) + 104
    If Month(Now) >= 4 Then Financial_year = Financial_year + 1
    Application = "ST"
    DefKey$     = Cstr(Financial_year)
    DefNo&      =  0
    Set RefDoc  =  RefView.GetDocumentByKey(DefKey$ , True)
    If Not(RefDoc Is Nothing) Then DefNo& = Clng(Right$(RefDoc.SETTLEMENT_NO(0),5))
    DefNo&      =  DefNo& + 1
    RefNo$      =  (Application + DefKey$) & "-" & Right$("00000" & Cstr(DefNo&) ,5)
    Doc.SETTLEMENT_NO= RefNo$
    Doc.FinFlag="Finish"
    Call SESS.SetEnvironmentVar("ENV_SETT",Right$("00000" & Cstr(DefNo&) ,5))
    Call uidoc.Refresh

Else
    Exit Sub
End If

get_ex_rate
get_cv_local
set_flag

Dim answer2 As Integer

answer2% = Msgbox("Do you want to save this document?", 1, "Save")
If answer2 = 1 Then 

    Petro$= uidoc.FieldGetText("Park_Petro_Car")
    Vehicle$=   uidoc.FieldGetText("Vehicle_No")
    Gifts$ = uidoc.FieldGetText("Gifts")
    Gifts_Ent$ = uidoc.FieldGetText("Gifts_Ent")
    Medical$ = uidoc.FieldGetText("Medical")
    Medical_Fee$ = uidoc.FieldGetText("Medical_Fee")
    Others$=    uidoc.FieldGetText("Others")
    OS$=    uidoc.FieldGetText("Others_Specify")
    Taxi$ = uidoc.FieldGetText("Taxi")
    Taxi_Fee$ = uidoc.FieldGetText("Taxi_Fee")
    If Petro$ <> "" And Vehicle$ = "" Then
        Msgbox "Please enter Vehicle No" , 16, "Vehicle No"
    Else 
        If  Gifts$ <> "" And Gifts_Ent$ = "" Then
            Msgbox "Please enter Guest/Co.Name" , 16, "Guest/Co.Name"
        Else
            If Medical$ <> "" And Medical_Fee$ = "" Then
                Msgbox "Please enter Medical_Fee" , 16, "Medical_Fee"
            Else
                If Taxi$ <> "" And Taxi_Fee$ = "" Then
                    Msgbox "Please enter Taxi Fee" , 16, "Taxi Fee"
                Else
                    If Others$ <> "" And OS$ = "" Then
                        Msgbox "Please enter Others(Specify)" , 16, "Others (Specify)"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If  

End If  

If answer2 = 2 Then
    continue=False
    Exit Sub
End If
uidoc.Refresh
'uidoc.close
```

End Sub

Comment: Please add some code.  It's impossible to guess why your code isn't working if you don't show it.

Comment: Can you re-accept the correct answer. Also please don't ask duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Else from your first IF Statement, otherwise the validation only runs once, when IsNewDoc returns True, once the doc has been saved once it will return False and your QuerySave Subroutine exits.

ELSE
    Exit Sub <-- remove this, your validation code only runs once per document.
End IF

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for adding the code.

With the "`If uidoc.IsNewDoc = True Then`" you explicitly tell the code to only run when the document is new.
So either add an appropriate elseif branch or get rid of the if itself and modify the validation accordingly so it applies to new and modified documents.

Comment: actually the first part of the code i.e., settlement number generation should happen for only new document and the field validation should happen for both new and modified documents.